# moveitematpath swift "/"character

Tags: ios, swift2, nsstring

I'm allowing the user to rename a file by using the `moveitematpath`. 
The user enters new name in a `UITextField`
If user enters "/" then the file is renamed but moved to a different folder.

Am I "allowed" to replace "/" by using `replaceoccurenceofstring`?
What else should I be looking for?

Thanks

Comment: You can replace "/" by ":", compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064907/swift-using-slash-in-filename-with-createdirectoryatpath for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

File names in MacOS X and iOS can contain any character except the nul character and a /. The correct way to handle this is to filter out "/" characters when the are entered. If I enter ab/cd I expect the new name to be ab/cd.That's not possible, but I don't expect that it will be named abcd. Instead it should not be possible for me to enter ab/cd in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. I'm telling the user NOT to enter "/" in the name. However I'm replacing it with "_" at the moment.

Comment: Is the ":" allowed?